# Get checked items id from custom listview and pass them to new activity android

Tags: android, json, listview, checkbox, bundle

I'm developing an android app which has a custom listview with a checkbox. I want to pass all the checked items from one activity to another. how should I pass them? and where should I manage the checkbox (to get all the checked items) in the custom adapter or the activity?

Note: I retrieve all the data from my server using json response.

Here's my Model :

```
  public class Groups {
        public String name;
        public boolean selected= false;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public Groups() {
        }
    }
```

My Adapter:

public class AdapterMainActivity extends BaseAdapter{

```
Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Groups> groupsList;

public AdapterMainActivity(Activity activity, List<Groups> groupses) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.groupsList = groupses;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return groupsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return groupsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        final Groups groups = groupsList.get(position);
        name.setText(groupsList.get(position).getName());

        checkBox.setChecked(groups.selected);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                groups.selected = isChecked;
                MainActivity.getInstance().updateArrayList(groupsList);
            }
        });


    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listViewGroups;
    Button buttonSentToActivity;

    List<Groups> groupsList;
    List<Groups> resultGroupList;
    ArrayList<Boolean> areChecked;
    List<String> finalArray;

    private AdapterMainActivity adapterMainActivity;

    static MainActivity yourActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        yourActivity = this;

        groupsList= new ArrayList<Groups>();
        resultGroupList= new ArrayList<Groups>();

        ReadGroup(37);

        adapterMainActivity = new AdapterMainActivity(this, groupsList);

        listViewGroups = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewGroups);
        listViewGroups.setAdapter(adapterMainActivity);

        buttonSentToActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSendTo2Activity);
        buttonSentToActivity.setOnClickListener(buttonSentToActivityListener);

        Log.e("Group list size ", String.valueOf(groupsList.size()));
        finalArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultGroupList.size(); i++) {
            if (resultGroupList.get(i).selected) {
                finalArray.add(resultGroupList.get(i).getName());
                Log.e("final array size", String.valueOf(finalArray.size()));
            }
        }

    }
    public void ReadGroup(long cid) {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONArray readArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("groups");

                    for (int i = 0; i < readArray.length(); i++) {

                        Log.e("i is: ", String.valueOf(i));
                        JSONObject jssonRow = readArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String groupName = jssonRow.getString("name");

                        Groups groups = new Groups();
                        groups.setName(groupName);
                        Log.e("NAME is: ", groupName);
                        groupsList.add(groups);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapterMainActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        Log.e("Client id is: ", String.valueOf(cid));
        ReadGroupRequesr readGroupRequest = new ReadGroupRequesr(cid, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue.add(readGroupRequest);

        Log.e("out of the loop", "");
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return yourActivity;
    }

    public void updateArrayList(List<Groups> arrayList) {
        this.resultGroupList = arrayList;
    }

    View.OnClickListener buttonSentToActivityListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Bundle b= new Bundle();
            //b.putStringArrayList("arrayList", (ArrayList<String>) finalArray);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayList", (ArrayList<String>) finalArray);
            //intent.putExtras(b);
            Log.e("final array size", String.valueOf(finalArray.size()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Adapter OnClickListner , get index and map to array stored in Activity. Change the checkbox state. While moving to another activity, pass the ArrayList of checked items

Comment: Please post some code, so that we can guide you for the same.

Comment: I've just posted my code... it works but the final array is always null!! even I checked the check box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for this Question:

My adapter:

```
public class ChooseContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<Contacts> contactsList;
public CheckBox checkBoxAdapter;

public ChooseContactsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Contacts> group) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.contactsList = group;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)             activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_choose_contacts_sms,
     null);

        final TextView fNAme = (TextView)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomSMSSelectContactFName);
        TextView LName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomSMSSelectContactLName);

        checkBoxAdapter = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSelectContact);

        checkBoxAdapter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                Contacts contacts = (Contacts) cb.getTag();
                contacts.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        final Contacts contacts = contactsList.get(position);


        fNAme.setText(contacts.getContactFName());
        LName.setText(contacts.getContactLName());
        checkBoxAdapter.setChecked(contacts.isSelected());
        checkBoxAdapter.setTag(contacts);
    }
    return convertView;
    }
    }
```

In my activity I have button to go from 1 activity to the 2 activity:

```
    private View.OnClickListener buttonSubmitGroupListener =new      View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       List <Integer> contactsIDArray= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Contacts> arrayOfContacts= chooseContactsAdapter.contactsList;
        for(int i=0; i< arrayOfContacts.size(); i++){
            Contacts contacts= arrayOfContacts.get(i);

            if(contacts.isSelected()==true){
                contactsIDArray.add(contacts.getContactID());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < contactsIDArray.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("Id Array size ", String.valueOf(contactsIDArray.size()));
            Log.e("Selected id ", String.valueOf(contactsIDArray.get(i)));
        }

        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendSMSActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putIntegerArrayList("checkedContacts", (ArrayList<Integer>) contactsIDArray);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Second Activity add this code:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    result = b.getIntegerArrayList("checkedContacts");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very first, manage your checkboxes :

In your activity class add a boolean array or arraylist having size same as your list array size and initialize it with all value as false initially :

```
String[] titlesArray;
ArrayList<Boolean> arrChecked;

// initialize arrChecked boolean array and add checkbox value as false initially for each item of listview
    arrChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    arrChecked.add(false);
    }
```

Now replace your adapter class with this :

```
class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titlesArray, descrptionArray;
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Boolean> arrChecked;

VivzAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, int[] images, String[] description, ArrayList<Boolean> arrChecked) {

super(context, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView1, titles);
this.context = context;
this.images = images;
this.titlesArray = titles;
this.descrptionArray = description;
this.arrChecked = arrChecked;

}

class MyViewHolder {
ImageView myImage;
TextView myTitle;
TextView myDescription;
CheckBox box;

MyViewHolder(View v) {
    myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
}
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
MyViewHolder holder = null;
if (row == null) {
    // 1.ºtime
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //row contem RelativeLayout(root) em single_row.xml
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
    row.setTag(holder);
    //Log.d("VIVZ", "Creating a new Row");
} else {
    //reciclamos aqui, qeremos usar antigo objecto holder
    holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    //Log.d("VIVZ", "Recycling stuff");
}
holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
holder.myTitle.setText(titlesArray[position]);
holder.myDescription.setText(descrptionArray[position]);

//set position as id
holder.box.setId(position);
//set onClickListener of checkbox rather than onCheckedChangeListener
holder.box.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            if (arrChecked.get(id)) {
                //if checked, make it unchecked
                arrChecked.set(id, false);
            } else {
                //if unchecked, make it checked
                arrChecked.set(id, true);

            }

        }
    });

    //set the value of each checkbox from arrChecked boolean array
    holder.box.setChecked(arrChecked.get(position));

return row;
}
}
```

After that, implement click listener of send button say btnSend button (I am considering that you are sending your data from one activity to another activity on click of send button) :

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> arrTempList = new ArrayList();
            for(int i=0; i<titles.size(); i++){
               if(arrChecked.get(i) == true){
                  arrTempList.add(titles[i]);
               }
            }

            // here you can send your arrTempList which is having checked items only

        }
    });
```

Comment: implements OnCheckedChangeListener.... you can't add this to the adapter without implement it's methods!